# PowerShell CreateSignificantWhitespace

Tags: xml, powershell, xmldocument

Consider the following PowerShell code snippet:

```
$xmldoc = New-Object xml
$xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true

# no error
$sigws1 = $xmldoc.CreateSignificantWhitespace(" ")

# error
$sigws2 = $xmldoc.CreateSignificantWhitespace("\n")
Exception calling "CreateSignificantWhitespace" with "1" argument(s): "The string for white space contains an invalid character."
At line:1 char:1
+ $sigws2 = $xml.CreateSignificantWhitespace("\n")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

According to current Microsoft documentation See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createsignificantwhitespace?view=net-5.0 for example, the following are valid whitespace "characters":

```
&#20; &#10; &#13; and &#9;
```

What is the correct way to include a newline/linefeed in the argument string?

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell uses the backtick `` ` `` as an escape character:

```
$sigws1 = $xmldoc.CreateSignificantWhitespace("`n")
```

See the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.